# How to set the index of a Series to the row number?

Tags: python, pandas, series

Suppose I have a `Series`,

```
s = Series(range(10))
a = s[s % 2 == 0]
```

then `a` will be like

```
0    0
2    2
4    4
6    6
8    8
```

What I want to do is set the index of `a` to the row number, which is

```
0    0
1    2
2    4
3    6
4    8
```

How to make it happen then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `reset_index`

```
a = s[s % 2 == 0].reset_index(drop=True)
```